# Windows Indexing filling up with hidden files

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop-services, indexing-service

How can I see or control why Windows Indexing is filling up this drive?

See this report from Tree Size (as Administrator):
[image: Drive is full with hidden files]

Only about 200 GB is reported, but Windws says 254 GB used.

Now when I rebuild the Windows Index database:

[image: Windows Index rebuilding]

135 GB is freed up!

Where did all that space came from?

I have changed settings for indexing so it only index users Outlook, but this still happen every 2 weeks or so.

Comment: So you are indexing over 100GB of OST / PST?

Comment: Yes, I am, why?

Comment: The content density is massive.  How much storage do you think it should take to store a comprehensive index of messages, contents, text, senders, recipients etc?

Comment: Also, you're almost certainly doing it wrong.  I can't think of a single good reason to be indexing a massive set of OST / PSTs.  Have you heard of 'mail archiving'?

Comment: Much less that the actually e-mails? As attachments and images won't need to be saved. 

There are 14 ost-files, 3 biggest are about 20 GB, as Office 365 max is 50 GB I can't see why that is too much.
I do indexing of Outlook so searching for e-mails don't take forever.

Comment: But my issue is who took the 50 GB of non existing files/folders.. Indexing is now complete: 1300000 items indexed. Size of the index is just over 5 GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not had this issue in a long time now, so I think it's time to close.

I also created a thread on [MS Partner forum](http://partnersupport.microsoft.com/en-us/mpndataplat/forum/mpncatwinsvr-mpnws2012/windows-indexing-filling-up-with-hidden-files/0ec92323-dade-4d04-aee7-5c9beeca4b3e?page=1), but it didn't bring anything new.